# MockBean seemingly being ignored for Scoped Proxy Bean when running tests in series

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito, junit5

I'm working on unit tests for a Spring Boot MVC Controller with some session-scoped beans, and while the application works as expected, unit tests are proving to be troublesome for an unknown reason and I'm looking to understand a bit more about why.

The bean config looks like this:

```
@Bean(name="scopedBean")
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION,
    proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public MyScopedBean myScopedBean() {
    return new MyScopedBean();
}
```

The controller looks something like this:

```
@Autowired
private ISomeService service;
@Autowired
private MyScopedBean scopedBean;

@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView getRequest(ModelAndView model, @RequestParam("id") UUID id) {

    if(scopedBean.matches(id)){
        //do some stuff
    }
    //return a page

}
```

There are other methods in the class which get, set and check against values in the scopedBean.

The tests look something like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
@Import({ActualValidator.class,SecurityConfig.class})
class MyControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @MockBean
    private ISomeService someService;
    @MockBean
    private MyScopedBean scopedBean;

    @Test
    void testA() throws Exception {

        when(scopedBean.getAValue()).thenReturn("myvalue");
        when(scopedBean.matches("someProperty").thenReturn(false);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(view().name("something");
    }

    @Test
    void testB() throws Exception {

        when(scopedBean.getAnotherValue()).thenReturn("othervalue");
        when(scopedBean.matches("anotherProperty").thenReturn(true);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(view().name("somethingelse");
    }

}
```

Each test, when ran individually, passes. When running them all together, they don't just fail, they return null pointers from *inside the mocked proxy* as if the object had been properly instantiated. I may be misunderstanding the concept of `@MockBean` but it was my understanding that the object shouldn't be actually instantiated? Is it possible this is because it's an actual object and not an interface?

I've tried configuring a la [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes), although the article talks about running as `@SpringBootTest` rather than a stripped back MVC test. Adding that config as context configuration causes all tests to start returning nulls for redirectedUrls, views, etc. as if it's not being set up correctly - which it probably isn't.

Is there something very obvious that I'm missing as to how my tests could sometimes seemingly be using a non-mocked object?

EDIT:

The plot thickens! Just for kicks, I decided to add a sysout to the start of a few of the controller methods which print out the value of the bean, hoping to get a memory address.

For every test which passes, it prints `scopedBean bean`.

For the tests which *fail*, it prints **an actual toString** a la `MyScopedBean(valueA=null, valueB=null, valueC=null)` - which seems...wrong. Call me crazy, but that sounds like it's actually creating an object there?

EDIT 2:

I've [raised this with the Spring team](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/30495) - at first glance it may look related to [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17817), however removing `@SessionScope` doesn't resolve the problem. Nor does adding mockito-inline. Swapping to `@SpyBean` results in slightly more consistency - but `doReturn`s are still seemingly ignored.

Comment: In case anyone sees this before a kind soul provides a proper answer, a bargain basement solution I've discovered is adding @DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD) to the test class. But this is a nasty fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution *is* to add `mockito-inline` for static methods - but unfortunately I'd also made an error further down my controller, which was the real culprit.

Anything created as as `@MockBean` can still be overridden - so in one of my methods I'd done:

`scopedBean = new ScopedBean();`

...to "reset" it. Works fine in practice - except when you test, this means that the mock is replaced with a real version of the bean, and because the tests reuse the same context the "mock" will then be useless.

I instead created a method which resets it without reinstantiating. `mockito-inline` is no longer required.